# Cakephp combine two or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays

How can I combine for example this arrays?

```
(int) 0 => array(
    'Test' => array(
        'id' => '108',
        'bericht' => '12',
        'fzge' => '35'
        'treiber' => 'Analyse'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Test' => array(
        'id' => '109',
        'bericht_id' => '12',
        'fzge' => '25',
        'treiber' => 'Analyse'
    )
)
```

The result that I want is somethings like: 'Analyse' => '60', so I would like to sum the "fzge" if "treiber" is the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share an example of the result you expect; it's currently unclear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code. Considering keys like ('Test', 'treiber' and 'fzge') of array remain same for all arrays

```
// declare new array
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $new_array[$value['Test']['treiber']] = (isset($new_array[$value['Test']['treiber']])) ? $new_array[$value['Test']['treiber']]+$value['Test']['fzge'] : $value['Test']['fzge'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Analyse] => 60
)
```